# Hiding a slider from specific pages within a template with php

Tags: php, html, hide

I am putting together an online store using TomatoCart.  The platform utilises a template system.

I have used a slider which has HTML, CSS and JavaScript.  The installation is pretty straightforward and it's displaying nicely on the site.

The problem is that it is now displaying on all pages and it is only required on the index page.  I have looked around and there seems to be a way of doing this via php.

Following this project I am making it my mission to learn php, but in the meantime could anybody explain to me how I can make the slider visible only on one page not all.  It is held in divs and the file name is index.php

Thank you

Comment: Sorry been sitting at the computer too long obviously!  Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if (strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], 'index.php') !== false) 
{
// add the slider  code here
}
?>

Here we just check if the page is index.php or not.  If it is it will execute the code within the if condition.


Regards
Abnab
```